# How to make video resolution setting permanent?

Tags: display, display-resolution

For some reason my Ubuntu 14.04 installation does not recognize my screen and therefore won't set the correct resolution. It defaults to something huge like `640x480`.

I found a way to set the required setting as follows:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

which I ran in a terminal.

Unfortunately, this does not set the settings permanently and I have to re-run each line after reboots.

How/Where can I set these lines/settings as default?

```
lspci -v | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

---

The commands above worked well until I did a complete new install with the latest OS core. Now I get: "cvt 1920 1080 60 # 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync"

"xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync X Error of failed request: BadName (named color or font does not exist) Major opcode of failed request: 140 (RANDR) Minor opcode of failed request: 16 (RRCreateMode) Serial number of failed request: 28 Current serial number in output stream: 28" What has changed? Or better yet, what should I change to get it working again? All help is greatly appreciated. Kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

You can reconfigure xOrg. I did this by creating a file in my `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` Directory.

I made it using vim:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/5-monitor.conf
```

Here is an example of my file

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "Monitor0"
   Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
   Modeline "3840x2160_30.0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
   Modeline "4096x2160_24.0" 297.00 4096 5116 5204 5500 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
EndSection
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Device0"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
   Identifier "Screen0"
   Device "Device0"
   Monitor "Monitor0"
   DefaultDepth 24
   SubSection "Display"
      Depth 24
      Modes "3840x2160" "1920x1080"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

For directions on how to do this you can follow this tutorial: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xorg/Multiple_monitors

I was ran into this issue with ubuntu 16.0.4

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr --addmode VGA 1920x1080_60.00
```

Only Last tell a reboot  you can make it permanent

```
.xprofile
```

Just copy and paste the `xrandr` command line strings into your user `~/.xprofile` file so it executed when you log in

Comment: Maybe for root as well , i.e. `/root/.xprofile`,  to also apply for the login screen?