# KDE Plasma suddenly not showing display resolution above 1080p

Tags: display, kde, display-resolution, plasma, displayport

I've been trying to get this back all night but I've failed so I thought I'd come here and ask.

I was moving my machine (HP Z240 with standard Intel graphics) running Ubuntu Studio 21.10 that was running at 2K resolution. Had a mishap with the DisplayPort cable. Plugged another in and the highest resolution I'm offered is 1080p. Used another cable bought only a month ago, still 1080p.

I did some fiddling with xrandr and for a short while I had 4K running at a very low refresh rate (the original reason for choosing 2K), so at least i know the cable's not the problem. Where have the other resolutions gone? And how can I get them back?

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

EDIT:

After I did some searching I found a way to decode the display's EDID file using read-edid. This gave me all the modes available for the display. I still don't understand why these are not being read by the system.

Anyway, I found the mode:

"Mode 1" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync

which looked very similar to what I had been using. I renamed this mode and then created it as a new one using xrandr. It appeared in settings and allowed me to switch to it.

To make these changes permanent the only suggestion i've found is to run my xrandr script as a batchfile at startup. Is this the only way? And I still have no idea why the original settings are no longer shown.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The native resolution is 4K 3840 x 2160, however when I first set this up - when the resolutions were available to me - I was presented this option only at 24Hz. This is why I went for the next option down that KDE offered me which worked perfectly for me; though I can't recall if it was at 60Hz or a fraction below it. I'm using the term 2K because I can't remember exactly what it was because it's disappeared.

Comment: No additional adapter. I'm using:
CPU: Intel i7-6700 (8) @ 4.000GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 

"Mode 1" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync

Comment: No additional adapter. I'm using:
CPU: Intel i7-6700 (8) @ 4.000GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 

The display is connected via a displayport to HDMI cable. I don't think the HD Graphics is capable of that at 60Hz - I was only given 24Hz when I connected it. 

I did some digging around and managed to decode the EDID file and found the following:

"Mode 1" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync

I created a mode in xrandr for this and applied it and it works perfectly.

However, I'm not sure how to make this change permanent? All info I can find is over 10y old!

Comment: Done. Inexpensive monitors with native displayport are few and far between :-)

Comment: What is the xrandr script?  Does your PC not have a HDMI port?

Comment: No it doesn't. HP PCs aimed at the corporate market never have HDMI, only DisplayPort. Refurbed ex-corporate machines are excellent value for money.

Comment: OK well in that case, answering my other question would be a step forward...  Can you post the script you are using? Can you share a link to the 10 year old info about how to make the xrandr settings permanent? Did you see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/979183) using xorg configs?